# List of average page number per journal

Tags: journals

There are lists of journals in various fields of science by impact factor, cites per document, total cites, etc.

Does there exist something comparable if I want to know the average number of pages per article?

Comment: Perhaps you could say more about why you want to know this information in order to receive an answer more focused on your motivating problem?

Comment: It is also true that different  journals may have different size pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no certain rule of thumb for determining the number of pages in a journal article. If you are asking for a sheet with all the information about it, then I think nobody here is going to be able to help you out. If you need information on a specific journal, however, then you may look into the journal's "Author Information/Instruction" page or "Paper Submission Page".

However, you should also note that there are often three different types of paper welcomed by many journals:

1. Short paper (least number of pages) E.g. 8 pages for IEEE
2. Regular paper (more pages) e.g. typically 12 double column pages
3. Review papers (most pages). e.g. I don't know.

However, everything depends again on publishers, including whether it is a double column or a single column format. Typically single column formats have higher page numbers than the examples given above.